# java: package sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper is not visible

Tags: java, pkcs#11

how to solve this error

java: package sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper is not visible
(package sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper is declared in module jdk.crypto.cryptoki, which is not in the module graph)

Comment: Remove the code which is trying to use that package.  No one should be using sun.* classes directly.  Whatever your code is trying to do, there’s a better way to do it.

Comment: `sun.` package is internally used by Java, you shouldn't use them directly. There is a better library for the PKCS#11 wrapper. Look into this https://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/products/core-crypto-toolkits/pkcs11-wrapper/

Comment: @always_a_rookie While that might be true, using sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 is what manufacturers of hardware tokens (digicert, Sectigo, ...) currently have as the reference code to sign Java code with certificates on hardware token.